# QGIS Essen ruler problems with EPSG:3857

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.14

I am using QGIS version 2.14.3-Essen. I am pretty new to this so bear with me. I have 3 layers: one of river polygons in MN, one of lakes, and the last an OpenLayers plugin of Google Satellite.

I am using the ruler, and originally 90% of the data matched with previous information we had (I am double checking, you see). However, I lost my project and had to re-install the 3 layers. Now the ruler consistently measures about 1.5 times what it should be. For example, the distance should be 594 meters away, but when I use the QGIS ruler it now says it is 892 meters.

I thought it could have been the order in which I download the layers, but that did not seem to solve it. Then I thought a prj issue, however I cannot add the prj files separately as vectors. Other sources says that the prj is not the issue because the shp file will automatically read the prj (as well as the other files). So then, I thought it could be a "Set Layers CRS" problem. I am now in EPSG: 3857, but when I find the CRS for my area (Minnesota EPSG: 26793) it layers my 2 water body files over Africa...

This person seems to have had a similar problem:
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-December/010597.html

Their solution was to: "get correct measures by reprojecting your shapefiles into a suitable UTM srs [and] may have to change the project crs too." However, I am not exactly sure what this entails..

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 5):

This most probably is a projection settings issue. The setting of your project is automatically changed to EPSG:3857 (because you would otherwise have distorted satellite images or other tiled layers) as you can see in the bottom right corner in QGIS as soon as you add the Google Satellite layer:

[image: display of the projections settings of your project]

If you click on this notification you can "Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation":

[image]

Now, your two other layers are in EPSG:26793. No problem. Just make sure that they are set as such. Double click the layer name in the layer panel (or right click > Properties). On the `General` tab the Coordinate reference system should be set to EPSG:26793:

[image]

Now your QGIS Measure Line should work as expected.

The .prj files are generated every time you save a .shp. As long as you know what projection a .shp is in you can always generate them again. The structure of .prj files generated by ESRI software was(is?) sometimes not correctly interpreted by QGIS. Just make sure the correct EPSG is set in the layer properties and you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like you simply do know the concept of changing projections.
You do not set it in the properties, but you have to save the layer to a new file and while doing that, change the projection, so the resulting file is getting transformed.

Apart from that, do not use OpenLayers anymore! Digitizing based on that can lead to plain wrong results. The much better alternative is QuickMapServices Plugin now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a projection issue. The ruler is measuring in EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) and distorting the measurements. To get the right measures you have to enable On The Fly projection and click on File -> Project Properties -> General and there is an area to select an ellipsoid that is set to None / Planar. Selecting an ellipsoid and enabling On The Fly will force Qgis to measure using the ellipsoid instead of a Planar projection. Leave the mouse over the results of the ruler, wait a few seconds and see how Qgis is measuring distances.